# Combine duplicate geometries into single records with v.clean in QGIS 3.6

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I have a points file that contains multiple duplicate geometries.  I am using the QGIS "Processing Modeller" to clean up data, and want to identify duplicate point geometries and combine so that I have a single entity.

I used the "Delete Duplicate Geometries" command, and had a significant reduction in the number of records.  I was skeptical at first so used the GRASS command v.clean with "rmdupl" command and received two outputs:

- Cleaned
- Errors

I noted that the "Cleaned" file still had duplicates in it.  Is there another step to remove the "errors" from the "Cleaned" file that I am missing.

As it turns out the "Delete Duplicate Geometries" appears to have given the correct answer, but I am still unclear using v.clean as it looks like a powerful tool.